# How to calculate surface area of an aerofoil?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, aerodynamics

how do I find the surface area of ​​an airfoil? I know the Thickness distribution and camber line equation, but what I don't understand is which function should I consider when calculating the surface area, for instance, how is the surface area of ​​the NACA 2412 airfoil calculated?

**For NACA 2412:**

Thickness distribution equation is given by:

$$\frac{t}{0.2}\left(0.2969\sqrt{x}-0.126x-0.3516x^{2}+0.2843x^{3}-0.1015x^{4}\right)\left\{0\le x\le1\right\}$$

where $t$ is the maximum thickness as a fraction of the chord. So here $t$ is equal to %12 of chord length

And the camber line equation given by: $$0.125\left(0.8x-x^{2}\right)\ \left\{0\le x\le0.4\right\}$$

$$\frac{1}{18}\left(0.2+0.8x-x^{2}\right)\left\{0.4\le x\le1\right\}$$

Comment: Seems like you need to find the arc length of the function $f(x)$, where $f$ is 1/2 the thickness at location $x$.  I suppose this problem assumes the wing is completely symmetric?

Comment: no its not symetric

Comment: The airfoil you've specified is a 2D shape. It has an arclength around its perimeter, but not an area. For that you would need to know the planform and integrate the arclength spanwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camber line equation traces a curve between $x = 0$ and $x = 1$. Let us denote it by $y(x)$. The length element along this curve is $dl = \sqrt{(dx)^2 + (dy)^2} = \sqrt{1 + {y^\prime}^2}dx$, where $y^\prime = dy/dx$. The area of the portion of aerofoil at this line element is $2 \times t(x) \times dl$, where $t$ is the thickness function. The factor of $2$ arises because the length of the upper and lower portions is each given by $t(x)$. Therefore the area is
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
A = \int_0^1 2t(x)\sqrt{1 + {y^\prime}^2}dx.
\end{equation}
In your case, since the camber line is described by two different functions in different part of the interval $[0, 1]$, we will have to write
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
A = \int_0^{0.4} 2t(x)\sqrt{1 + {y_1^\prime}^2}dx + \int_{0.4}^1 2t(x)\sqrt{1 + {y_2^\prime}^2}dx,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{eqnarray}
y_1^\prime(x) &=& 1 - \frac{x}{4} \\
y_2^\prime(x) &=& \frac{0.4 - x}{9}
\end{eqnarray}
The integration can be easily carried out numerically.